# set value as header using pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have set of output values as shown below

1,2,3

val1,val2,val3

4,5,6

But I require the header to appear first.  output must be like below

val1,val2,val3

1,2,3

4,5,6

Comment: Whats your input and output steps? Depending on it you can use different solutions.

Comment: I have formed the header using the step 'Generate rows' and the values is from a csv file and the output is a csv .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your description and comment correctly, you have an input csv file without headers and want to write (static) headers in the output csv.

The easiest way is to name the fields val1, val2, val3 in the csv input step and in the text file output step make sure to check the "headers" box in the content tab.

Alternatively, you can use the "Append streams" step after your Generate Rows and CSV File Input steps to merge them in an ordered way. Choose the Generate Rows as the head step and the header record will go first.